# ExtJS: dateField - how to disable all and enable some dynamic array dates

Tags: extjs, datefield

How can I disable all calendar dates and enable from dynamic array?

For example, I have array

```
['1.12.21', '25.11.21', '3.12.21', '8.10.21']
```

I should disable all dates exceptdates from array - how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Ext.form.field.Date` `disabledDates` configuration, and `setDisabledDates` method to update it, see in the [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Date.html#cfg-disabledDates). The array you specify here will be interpreted as a regular expression, so in your case you can set up a negated condition to disable all but some dates.

Try the code below, also [this working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3gj2). This works in classic toolkit, I don't know how to do it in modern.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        const enabledDatesArray = ['01.10.21', '06.10.21', '15.10.21'];
        const disabledDatesRegex = '^(?!'+enabledDatesArray.join('|')+').*$';
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            width: 400,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'datepicker',
                format: 'd.m.y',
                disabledDates: [disabledDatesRegex]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Good to hear, you are welcome.